# Get all Regions of HBase avoiding Zookeeper client reconnection

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

for project requirement I need to extract HBase metadata for all regions.
Precisely for each region I need this fields:

- Schema name
- Table name
- Encode name
- Start key
- End key

So I came up with this solution:

```
List<HTableDescriptor> hTableDescriptors = Arrays.asList(admin.listTables());
        for (HTableDescriptor hTableDescriptor : hTableDescriptors) {
            TableName name = hTableDescriptor.getTableName();
            List<HRegionInfo> tableRegions = admin.getTableRegions(name);
            LOG.info("Found {} regions",tableRegions.size());
            for (HRegionInfo region : tableRegions) {
                RegionDetailInfo detailInfo = new RegionDetailInfo();
                detailInfo.setSchemaName(name.getNamespaceAsString());
                detailInfo.setTableName(name.getNameAsString());
                detailInfo.setEncodeName(region.getEncodedName());
            detailInfo.setStartKey(Bytes.toString(region.getStartKey()));
                    detailInfo.setEndKey(Bytes.toString(region.getEndKey()));
/* other stuff */
                }
            }
```

The problem here is that the statement: `admin.getTableRegions(name);`
need to establish a zookeeper connection for every table.
So reading metadata is very very slow.

Is there any other way to accomplish the same task?